# Linux - configure TI AM335X MDIO when connected to Marvell's switch

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, switching

I have a board with Sitara AM3352 - the networking is not via Ethernet PHY, but with a switch (Marvell 88E6341) that is connected to the CPU with MII. the switch has a port that is connected to a PHY and RJ45 connector.

My Linux version is 4.14

I configured the dts file correctly for having a network, but I also want the MDIO driver to be active so I will be able to manage the switch.

It looks like I can interact the Sitara MDIO controller with "devmem" commands, but I prefer to do it the "normal" way with the kernel devinci-mdio driver.

My dts looks like this:

```
&cpsw_emac0 {
phy_id = <&davinci_mdio>, <0>;
fixed-link = <1 1 100 0 0>;
phy-mode = "mii";
};

&mac {
slaves = <1>;
pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
pinctrl-0 = <&cpsw_default>;
pinctrl-1 = <&cpsw_sleep>;
status = "okay";
};

&davinci_mdio {
compatible = "ti,cpsw-mdio";
pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
pinctrl-0 = <&davinci_mdio_default>;
pinctrl-1 = <&davinci_mdio_sleep>;
status = "okay";
};
```

This what I get in the dmesg:

```
[ 0.975182] mdio_bus fixed-0: GPIO lookup for consumer reset
[ 0.975195] mdio_bus fixed-0: using lookup tables for GPIO lookup
[ 0.975202] mdio_bus fixed-0: lookup for GPIO reset failed
[ 0.975223] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[ 0.994386] mdio_bus 4a101000.mdio: GPIO lookup for consumer reset
[ 0.994398] mdio_bus 4a101000.mdio: using lookup tables for GPIO lookup
[ 0.994405] mdio_bus 4a101000.mdio: lookup for GPIO reset failed
[ 1.047323] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: davinci mdio revision 1.6, bus freq 1000000
[ 1.055025] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: no live phy, scanning all
[ 1.061484] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: mdiobus_register ret=-5
```

I think it is rather common such design - so if anybody managed to handle this issue, I will much appreciate it if he will share the knowledge.
Thanks

Comment: I guess the ones that vote against this post don't have a clue on what the question is about. This issue is very common to whoever uses a board with Sitara with networking via a switch. and believe me, I search and I didn't find the answer. I think that if someone has experience with it - it will be a big deal to share it

Comment: I guess the ones that voted against this post realized that it's not a programming question and so unsuitable for stack-overfow. Maybe try [sf] (but read their help first to confirm it's suitable)

Comment: It is embedded programming - it involves Linux kernel programming and device tree description

Answer (score 1):

Active the devinci_mdio kernel driver for a network switch is not trivial, but it must in order to use the Marvell software package to manage the switch.
So instead of using the kernel driver - it is possible to access the MDIO controller physical addresses from the Linux userspace with the"`mmap`" command:

- In am3352 the MDIO controller address is 0x4a101000 - map this address, the length should be 0x90 bytes.
- Enable the controller in the address 0x4a101004 with the data 0x410000ff (the ff is for the clock speed, so another value is possible)
- Read and write will be with address 0x4a101080.

Now you can implement the MDIO read and write functions that are required for Marvell's software package (or for other software packages)